# Visualização de edição difere da edição real

Tags: bug, status-intencional, edição, markdown

Veja [essa revisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/17192/2). Pode ver fragmentos em **negrito** logo na primeira linha. Agora abra a [resposta original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17192/41056) e perceba que esse negrito sumiu e fica somente o texto `**` no lugar.

Veja a divergência:

> limite teórico de 2**31 - 1 (32bits) ou 2**63 - 1 (64bits) -- visualização de edição

vs

> limite teórico de 2**31 - 1 (32bits) ou 2**63 - 1 (64bits) -- real

<del>Deveria mostrar como realmente é, sem os negritos, escapando o caractere `*`.</del>

Deveria mostrar em negrito, conforme apontado pelo @bfavaretto, em qualquer situação, já que aparentemente **não foi utilizado nenhum caractere de escape**.

Copiar e colar o markdown da resposta [em outro lugar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/6561/2) não gera o mesmo resultado. Aparece com negrito em todos os casos.

Ocorre [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/17192/2), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/17192/revisions) (exceto na visualização markdown) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17192/41056) (ao clicar em "Editar")

[image]

---

## English Version

**Title:** Edit preview is different from actual edit

Look at [this revision](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/17192/2). You can see fragments in **bold** right in the first line. Now open [the original answer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17192/41056) and see how that bold formatting is gone and you can only see the plaintext `**` in its place.

See the difference:

> limite teórico de 2**31 - 1 (32bits) ou 2**63 - 1 (64bits) -- edit preview

vs

> limite teórico de 2**31 - 1 (32bits) ou 2**63 - 1 (64bits) -- actual post after edit

It should be shown in bold, since **no escape character was used**.

Copying and pasting the markdown from the answer [elsewhere](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/6561/2) does not produce the same results. It shows in bold in all instances.

It happens [here](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/17192/2), [here](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/17192/revisions) (except in the markdown visualization) and [here](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17192/41056) (by clicking "Edit").

[image]

Comment: As edições não deveriam mostrar o que é novo com fundo verde?

Comment: A minha dúvida é o oposto da sua: por que na resposta aparecem os ** em vez de gerarem um negrito? Não há nenhum escape visível deles.

Comment: Não que eu saiba. Mas vai que o Maniero conhece algum truque com caracteres unicode exóticos...

Comment: Então @bfavaretto eu duvido um pouco que o interpretador de markdown sejam diferentes, mas será que existe a remota possibilidade do interpretador ser uma versão diferente (mais antiga) na tela de revisões? Ou talvez seja um bug mesmo, levando em consideração que SO não atualizou o markdown devido ao markdown de tabelas que poderia conflitar, o Github mesmo a um ano atrás modificou o markdown e afetou todos o "titulos" (`#` e `##` por exemplo), muitos "README.md"s ficaram falhados. Eu pensei na possibilidade também de algum parametro estar mal-configurado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu acho que deve ser o mesmo interpretador, com diferenças de implementação/integração nos diferentes contextos.

Comment: Que tal usar `limite teórico de 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 (32 bits) ou 2<sup>63</sup> - 1 (64 bits) -- real`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme explicado [neste post no MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240354/208518), isto é um comportamento intencional.

Uma das razões para este funcionamento são língua onde não se usam espaços entre palavras (como em Japonês, por exemplo).

Comment: É intencional que apareça de uma maneira [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/17192/2) e de outra [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17179/quais-s%C3%A3o-os-limites-de-tamanho-das-vari%C3%A1veis-em-ruby/17192#17192)?

Comment: Vejo igual nos dois...

Comment: Então foi corrigido. Veja no gif do post.

Comment: Sim, eu vi. O Shog forçou esse post em particular a actualizar. Seja como for, isso estava a acontecer porque os posts antigos não mudavam a formatação a não ser que actualizasses a página — caso contrário, tinhas um bom molho de posts antigos para corrigir...

Comment: Agora faz sentido.. Obrigado :P